# Why I am getting SQL syntax error during runtime while all of my codes look fine?

Tags: runtime-error, syntax-error

I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar2(20),sal number)' at line 1`

This is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.text.html.CSS;

public class Manual_entry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Name");
    String Name=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("you entered name" +Name);
    System.out.println("Enter salary");
    int sal =s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("you entrd salary" +sal);
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_db","root","root");
        Statement cs = con.createStatement();
        int i=cs.executeUpdate("create table student2(name varchar2(20),sal number)");
        i=cs.executeUpdate("insert into student2 values('"+Name+"',"+sal+")");
        ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery("select*from student2");
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("name= " +rs.getString(1) +"salary= " +rs.getInt(2));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    }
}
```